How to do not produce Python3 prefix when using the Python source code to build a DEB package?
I had set setup.py in my python project 'name', 'py_modules', 'entry_points' value looks like 'abc';
and set debian/control Source, Package value looks like 'abc'……
but when I use the following command to build a Deb package:
python3 setup.py sdist --format=gztar

python3 setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb

It will generate the Deb package in the following name format:
deb_dist/python3-abc_xxx.deb
So how to do not produce Python3 prefix when using the Python source code to build a DEB package?
